# How can i prevent the ng-bootstrap modal to open on enter key?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am using modal from ng-bootstrap library.Once when i click on the button the modal is opened.If i click close the modal is closed and now if i press enter the modal automatic open and close on enter key without pressint on the modal button to open that modal

How can i solve this out of the box behaviour of the ng boostrap modal.
I tried with keyup listener but first modal open and after that is closed when i press enter

```
  @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
  keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13){      
        this.modalService.dismissAll();
    }
  }

public requestCoxContract(quoteId) {
    let options: NgbModalOptions = {
      backdrop: 'static',
      centered: true,
      keyboard: false
    };
    if (quoteId) {
      this.router.navigate(['/ibs/cox-contract']);
    } else {
      this.quoteRedirect = true;
      this.modalService.open(this.customerNameModal, options);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are having a form on which you are pressing enter? Its not problem of ngbmodal. you component maybe calling requestCoxContract when you press enter. Check it by putting a console log inside requestcoxcontract method.

Comment: @AakashGarg Thanks for your reply.I've checked when i press enter the code in the requestcoxcontract  method is not executed.It opens by default

Comment: Do you have any idea how this can be solved ?

Comment: you have any keyup.enter events in your application?

Comment: Yes,but first modal is opened and after that closed,keyup tis triggered after i close the modal.I updated my question.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: you are having any event on close of modal?

Comment: No  i don't have :(

Comment: provide a stackblitz then.

Comment: @Trajce12, be carafully. In Angular if you has a button and don't add `type="button"` this button is a defect button (like if you write type="submit"), and when you press enter key, execute the action of the button